# segmentation fault w/ fgets using struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, fgets

i'm still a beginner with coding; i'm writing a code to learn about structs and pointers but i get a segmentation fault when using `fgets`. here's the code

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define a 100
#define MAX 200

int i;
typedef struct libreria{
    char titolo[a];
    char autore[a];
    int anno;
    char genere[a];
}libro;

libro *libroptr;
int inserisci_libro(libro *libroptr){
    printf("Titolo: \n");
    fgets((libroptr->titolo),a,stdin); // here is where i get the error
    printf("Autore: \n");
    fgets((libroptr->autore),a,stdin);
    printf("Anno: ");
    scanf("%i",&libroptr->anno);
    printf("Genere: ");
    fgets((libroptr->genere),a,stdin);

    return 0;
};

void main(){
    //printf("%d\n",sizeof(libroptr->titolo));
    typedef struct libreria libro[MAX];
    inserisci_libro(libroptr);
    return;
}
```

the idea is to create a library of book that the user have to insert. once i run the code i get the error on the `fgets` in the function `inserisci_libro` but i can't understand why. if someone can help thanks a lot.

Comment: You pass a `NULL` pointer to your function. You must allocate some memory for `libroptr` to point to

Comment: Having 2 typedefs with same name but different types is not a good idea.

Comment: Start by removing the `typedef` from the line in `main( )`... There should be compiler warnings. Work through those first...

Comment: It is unclear how you want to manage a library. Do you want to use an array? Then you need an array variable, that array typedef doesn't help. Or do you want to use a linked list? Then you are missing a pointer to link the book nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined a null pointer

```
libro *libroptr;
```

and this null pointer is used to access memory as for example

```
fgets((libroptr->titolo),a,stdin);
```

So the program has undefined behavior.

You should define an object of the type `libro` in main as for example

```
libro libro_uno;
```

and pass a pointer to it to the function

```
inserisci_libro( &libro_uno );
```

And this declared typedef name as an alias for an array type

```
typedef struct libreria libro[MAX];
```

is not used in your program and will only confuse readers of the program because in the file scope there is already declared the alias `libro` for the structure type `struct libreria`.

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Comment: So the OP would need to allocate memory for it. For reference- https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-dynamic-memory-allocation